# Get specific fields in JSON

Tags: json, node.js

I have a problem with getting some JSON fields in NodeJS.
Here is my JSON structure:

```
{
    "header":
    {
        "file1":0,
        "file2":1,
        "subfiles":{
          "subfile1":"true",
          "subfile2":"true",
        }
    },

    "response":
    {
        "number":678,
        "start":0,
        "docs":[
            {
                "id":"d3f3d",
                "code":"l876s",
                "country_name":"United States",
                "city":"LA"
            },
            {
                "id":"d2f2d",
                "code":"2343g",
                "country_name":"UK",
                "city":"London"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

How to access to specific fields (id, city or country_name) in structure like this?
I'm trying something in NodeJS, but I cannot get specific fields.

```
request('http://url.com', function (error, res, body) {
  if (!error && res.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body) 
  }

    res.on('data', function(chunk){
        body += chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', function(){
        var urlResponse = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log("Got a response: ", urlResponse.response.docs.city);
    });
});
```

Comment: You have an array of "docs" so you'll have to pick one.

Answer (score 1):

Try using using a `data` variable to accumulate your chunks and then `data.toString()` to force the buffered content to string, which will be parseable JSON.

Additionally, you need to access the specific member of the `docs` array.

Comment: Can I use JSON.stringify(body) instead of toString()?

Comment: No, because the content is Buffered. You will need to convert that buffered content to string before parsing as JSON.

Comment: Can you accept this answer if it solves your issue @corry ?

Comment: Your answer has helped, but I still didn't solve the problem. Thanks

Comment: Please update your example and explain where you are still having issues. @corry

Comment: I still can't get value from array. I gave up from implementing this solution and I'm trying [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34950357/store-json-data-in-mysql-table?noredirect=1#comment57632549_34950357) Thank you

Comment: The above solution should work. In fact I have just completed a similar piece of code. How are you attempting to access your array elements? The method used above is not accurate. If you wanted to access a particular member of your array you would do so like this `urlResponse.response.docs[0].city` or you could use one of the loop examples suggested by others here. The solution you've chosen on the other SO question is definitely not standard. Good luck @corry! Let me know if you'd like to further explore this one.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this:

```
thatObject.response.docs.forEach((element) => { console.log( element.id ); });
```

?

property *docks* is an array, so you can use functions: forEach, or for, or whatever you wish

Comment: I'm trying with `for(var i = 0; i < data.response.docs.length; i++){
     var post  = data.response.docs[i];
     console.log(post);
 }` and I got Cannot read property 'docs' of undefined
 error

Comment: Hey! It looks like you use request module? I have never used it, but try something like this: (how to start writing a new line here?;))    replace `data` with `body`.